# Factoring a whole number power from a fractional power of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you factor 
 $x^{2}$ from 
$ \left(x^3+x^2\right)^{^{\frac{2}{3}}}+\left(x^3+x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^2 $?

I have tried making sense of it but I keep getting nowhere.

Comment: Assuming $x$ is a positive real., if you insist on writing this as $x^2\cdot (\text{stuff})$ you could do it by noting that $(x^3+x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}=(x^3(1+\frac{1}{x}))^{\frac{2}{3}}=(x^3)^{\frac{2}{3}}\cdot(1+\frac{1}{x})^{\frac{2}{3}}=x^2(1+\frac{1}{x})^{\frac{2}{3}}$.  Do so similarly for the second parenthetical phrase.

Comment: Thank you so much truly appreciate the help. Finally get where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(x^3+x^2\right)^{^{\frac{2}{3}}}+\left(x^3+x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^2$

$= \bigg(x^{3}(\frac{x^3}{x^3}+\frac{x^2}{x^3})\bigg)^\frac23+\bigg(x^6(\frac{x^3}{x^6}+\frac{x^2}{x^6})\bigg)^\frac13+x^2$

$= x^2\big(1+x^{-1})^\frac23+x^2(x^{-3}+x^{-4})^\frac13+x^2$

$= x^2\bigg[(1+x^{-1})^\frac23+(x^{-3}+x^{-4})^\frac13+1\bigg]$

Comment: Thank you, your assistance really helped solve the mess that was in my head.

Comment: no problem always happy to help:)